# Using composer to replace changed files in a library

Tags: php, composer-php

I was trying some things out with an installed library and ended up changing a few files. I'd like to revert these back to their original state. I know I could just delete the library and install it again but was wondering if there is a composer command to just replace the edited files only. I'm thinking in terms of something like "git reset --hard HEAD" or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library was installed from a zip file no it's not possible. Deleting the vendor/foo/bar directory and running composer install is the easiest way. If you have a git clone of the vendor though then obviously you can `git checkout .` to reset everything.

Comment: is this still the case?